# How does one actor get remote actor ip within one group?

Tags: ip, actor, c++-actor-framework

How does one actor get remote actor ip within one group?

For example, I have two actors A and B which both joined one group chatroom.
A and B were spawned on different machines.

Then B send one messge to the group and A can receive and act.
Now A wants to know the IP of B for each received message from B. Is there any way to implenment this function?

I found one similar answer from https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/issues/419. But I am not sure this is also proper for group.

Answer (score 1):

When receiving a message, you can get a handle to the sender by calling `self->current_sender()`. Then you can get the `node_id` from this handle and, if it's different from your own `node_id`, ask the middleman about connection details.

```
auto sender = self->current_sender();
if (!sender)
  return; // anonymous message
auto x = sender->node();
if (x == self->node())
  return; // not a remote actor
auto mm = system.middleman().actor_handle();
self()->request(mm, get_atom::value, x).receive(
  [&](const node_id& nid, const std::string& addr, uint16_t port) {
    assert(nid == x);
    cout << "address: " << addr << ", port = " << port << endl;
  }
);
```

However, this is not part of the stable API. This means it is likely to change, so keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In additinal, can one actor in the group fetch the IP of another actor which is also in the same group via group manager?

Comment: There's no way to retrieve members of a group since the group module is meant for loose coupling. When implementing a group in terms of UDP multicast, for example, there's no way to get the membership in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'll implement this function by other way, such as message.